# Why is Visual Studio 2013 crashing when I try to create/open a Multi-Device Hybrid Apps application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm attempting to create a first application and it crashes when I try to create or open a solution created from the template.

I have very basic debug information:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>   Additional information: The path is not of a legal form.

I already have an environment setup for Android Studio 0.8.0 and have installed ant previously in order to support robobinding in android.

Comment: Do you happen to have Web Essentials also installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, Web essentials is installed.

Comment: I have disabled Web Essentials and it seems to start up.  New problems now, I'll pose questions as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use web essentials with Multi-Device Hybrid Apps you can switch to nightly builds of Web Essentials.

Last time I tried that fixed the crashing for me.

You can find the nightly builds in this address http://vswebessentials.com/download

Burcu (MSFT)

Comment: Using the nightly builds also fixed the problem for me. Both for CTP 1.0, 1.1 and the most recent 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling Web essentials, the project was at least able to load.

Be sure to disable web essentials for now under the Tools > Extensions and Updates and look for Mads' web essentials extension.