# Multi-device hybrid apps + webessentials: bundling two css files gives error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, visual-studio-cordova

I use Multi-device hybrid apps CTP 2 with webessentials and try two bundle two css files. It gives the following error:

```
16-8-2014 22:58:19: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.FileHelpers.RelativePath(String absolutePath, String relativeTo)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleDocument.GetRelativePath(String file, String root)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleDocument.<>c__DisplayClass5.<WriteBundleRecipe>b__2(String file)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XName name, Object content)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleDocument.<WriteBundleRecipe>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleFilesMenu.<MakeBundleAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
```

The file **Mybundle.css.bundle** is created but:

1. Is empty
2. Is not included in the project

I included the **Mybundle.css.bundle** in the project, and added the required configurartion as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bundle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://vswebessentials.com/schemas/v1/bundle.xsd">
  <settings>
    <!--Determines if the bundle file should be automatically optimized after creation/update.-->
    <minify>true</minify>
    <!--Determin whether to generate/re-generate this bundle on building the solution.-->
    <runOnBuild>true</runOnBuild>
    <!--Use absolute path in the generated CSS files. By default, the URLs are relative to generated bundled CSS file.-->
    <adjustRelativePaths>true</adjustRelativePaths>
    <!--Specifies a custom subfolder to save files to. By default, compiled output will be placed in the same folder and nested under the original file.-->
    <outputDirectory />
  </settings>
  <!--The order of the <file> elements determines the order of the files in the bundle.-->
  <files>
    <file>/css/index.css</file>
    <file>/css/stylesheet.css</file>
  </files>
</bundle>
```

Compilation or saving one of the css files does not trigger bundling.

Do **Multi-device hybrid apps CTP 2** and **WebEssentials** work together?

Answer (score 0):

You should report these errors to Mads Kristensen at https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013

Answer (score 0):

Opened https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1429 as I too encountered similar error when bundling css using Web Essentials 2013 on Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP2.0

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answers to this question: [Why is Visual Studio 2013 crashing when I try to create/open a Multi-Device Hybrid Apps application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147493/why-is-visual-studio-2013-crashing-when-i-try-to-create-open-a-multi-device-hybr/25166696#25166696)

There are issues when Multi-device hybrid apps CTP2 and WebEssentials are installed together. Either you need to disable WebEssentials or switch to nightly builds of WebEssentials.